# How can I group unknown (but repeated) words to create an index?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have to create a shellscript that indexes a book (text file) by taking any words that are encapsulated in angled brackets (<>) and making an index file out of that. I have two questions that hopefully you can help me with!

**The first is how to identify the words in the text that are encapsulated within angled brackets.
I found a similar question that was asked but required words inside of square brackets and tried to manipulate their code but am getting an error.**

```
grep -on \\<.*> index.txt
```

**The original code was the same but with square brackets instead of the angled brackets and now I am receiving an error saying:**

```
line 5: .*: ambiguous redirect
```

**This has been answered**

I also now need to take my index and reformat it like so, from:

```
1:big
3:big
9:big
2:but
4:sun
6:sun
7:sun
8:sun
```

Into:

```
big: 1 3 9
but: 2
sun: 4 6 7 8
```

I know that I can flip the columns with an awk command like:

```
awk -F':' 'BEGIN{OFS=":";} {print $2,$1;}' index.txt
```

But am not sure how to group the same words into a single line.

Thanks!

Comment: You may consider `grep -oPn '<\K[^<>]+(?=>)' index.txt` to extract all occurrences of words inside angle brackets.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. Are you able to explain the regex to me (or can point me to a source that could)? So stuck on it!

Comment: An index would normally be more than just a list of words and numbers so it's not clear why that'd be useful output, nor do we know what your input looks like that you want to extract that text from nor what those numbers mean. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] concise, textual sample input and expected output so we can bet help you.

Comment: You're getting that ambiguous redirect error, btw, because `\\<.*>` is trying to do input/output redirection in a way that doesn't make sense. You probably meant `'<.*>'` instead but that's almost certainly wrong too (`'<[^<>]*>'` is more likely to be correct). Show us some input/output so we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following(if you are not worried about sorting order, in case you need to sort it then append `sort` to following code).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=":"
}
{
  name[$2]=($2 in name?name[$2] OFS:"")$1
}
END{
  for(key in name){
    print key": "name[key]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                       ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=":"                                     ##Setting field separator as : here.
}
{
  name[$2]=($2 in name?name[$2] OFS:"")$1      ##Creating array named name with index of $2 and value of $1 which is keep appending to its same index value.
}
END{                                         ##Starting END block of this code here.
  for(key in name){                          ##Traversing through name array here.
    print key": "name[key]                   ##Printing key colon and array name value with index key
  }
}
' Input_file                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `($2 in name)` is the idiomatic way.

Comment: @karakfa, Thank you sir, done that now, thanks for suggesting improvement sir.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract multiple occurrences of substrings in between angle brackets with GNU `grep`, you may consider a PCRE regex based solution like

```
grep -oPn '<\K[^<>]+(?=>)' index.txt
```

The PCRE engine is enabled with the `-P` option and the pattern matches:

- `<` - an open angle bracket
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `[^<>]+` - 1 or more (due to the `+` quantifier) occurrences of any char but `<` and `>` (see the `[^<>]` bracket expression)
- `(?=>)` - a positive lookahead that requires (but does not consume) a `>` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be what you need, it outputs the paragraph number, line number within the paragraph, and character position within the line for every occurrence of each target word:

```
$ cat book.txt
Wee, <sleeket>, cowran, tim’rous beastie,
O, what a panic’s in <thy> breastie!
Thou need na start <awa> sae hasty,
          Wi’ bickerin brattle!
I wad be laith to rin an’ chase <thee>
          Wi’ murd’ring pattle!

I’m <truly> sorry Man’s dominion
Has broken Nature’s social union,
An’ justifies that ill opinion,
          Which makes <thee> startle,
At me, <thy> poor, earth-born companion,
          An’ fellow-mortal!
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="\t" }
{
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=NF; lineNr++) {
        line = $lineNr
        idx = 1
        while ( match( substr(line,idx), /<[^<>]+>/ ) ) {
            word = substr(line,idx+RSTART,RLENGTH-2)
            locs[word] = (word in locs ? locs[word] OFS : "") NR ":" lineNr ":" idx + RSTART
            idx += (RSTART + RLENGTH)
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (word in locs) {
        print word, locs[word]
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk book.txt | sort
awa     1:3:21
sleeket 1:1:7
thee    1:5:34  2:4:24
thy     1:2:23  2:5:9
truly   2:1:6
```

Sample input courtesy of [Rabbie Burns](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43816/to-a-mouse-56d222ab36e33)

Answer (score 1):

To transform 
**index.txt**

```
1:big
3:big
9:big
2:but
4:sun
6:sun
7:sun
8:sun
```

into:

```
big: 1 3 9
but: 2
sun: 4 6 7 8
```

you can try this AWK program:

```
awk -F: '{ if (entries[$2]) {entries[$2] = entries[$2] " " $1} else {entries[$2] = $2 ": " $1} }
  END { for (entry in entries) print entries[entry] }' index.txt | sort
```

Shorter version of the same suggested by RavinderSingh13:

```
awk -F: '{ 
  { entries[$2] = ($2 in entries ? entries[$2] " " $1 : $2 ": " $1 }
  END { for (entry in entries) print entries[entry] }' index.txt | sort
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you help me understand it? So this part { if (a[$2])  {a[$2] = a[$2] "  " $1} means that if any entries in the second column are equivalent, then we make the second column value equalled to all the respective $1 separated by "  "? And then the else statement covers values that are unique and hence just flips the columns?

Comment: This is good, IMHO, this could be a bit shorter version(using wild operators `?` and `:` too) https://stackoverflow.com/a/61307771/5866580 too, cheers.

Comment: Explanation (I changed the name of the array from `a` into `entries`): for each line I read, I create an element `entries[$2]`. If this entry already exist, I append a white space `" "` to it, followed by the number `$1`; otherwise, I create an entry with the field `$2`, a colon and a space `": "`, and the number `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

GNU [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) is a handy tool for working on groups of columnar data (Plus some `sed` to massage its output into the right format):

```
$ grep -oPn '<\K[^<>]+(?=>)' index.txt | datamash -st: -g2 collapse 1 | sed 's/:/: /; s/,/ /g'
big: 1 3 9
but: 2
sun: 4 6 7 8
```